# PowerShell Graph module sporadically gives an error The term 'Microsoft.Graph.Sites.private\Get-MgSite_List' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell-cmdlet

With the last versions of Graph PowerShell module, from time to time when executing some Graph PowerShell cmdlets, it's failing saying that the term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. During the same execution window other cmdlets are recognized though.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfhDQ.jpg)

Uninstalling and reinstalling the Graph Module fixed the issue sometimes but it's not consistent

Uninstall-Module Microsoft.Graph